# How to add new tabs to my browser’s homepage when using Firefox version 57?

Tags: firefox

Before Firefox 57, I used to use an add-on called [My Homepage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/my-homepage/). If my homepage was Bing.com, this add-on would open all new tabs and go to Bing and the cursor would be set at the Bing search so I could begin searching.

Now, this add-on has been depricated and no longer works. Is there a way I can achieve this similar functionality with Firefox 57?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your default search engine to Bing, when you open a new tab, it positions your cursor in the address bar.  You can just type what you want to search, hit enter, and then it will search Bing.com.